# How high must a cliff be to fly a pig off of it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

How high does the cliff have to be in order to obtain the Minecraft achievement? Are there any other requirements? I've trapped a pig, saddled it, and am digging away around the enclosure to create a 'cliff'...

Comment: For the record, a depth of 5 works, I don't know if it's the minimum though...

Comment: A related question - can you now craft a saddle or do you still have to find one in a dungeon chest?

Comment: @ChrisF, agreed, a related question. Maybe you should actually ask it, and link it here. ;)

Comment: @ChrisF - the minecraft wiki's saddle page hasn't been updated with a saddle recipe, so I don't think anything's changed in that case.

Comment: @ChrisF You cannot craft a saddle

Comment: @Denilson - From what I knew you can't craft a saddle, but it's odd that the achievement route is via killing a cow to find leather - which is what made me think of it.

Comment: It has to do at least 1 damage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enough to take damage, so 3 blocks or more.

http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1043&t=303222

Comment: Does this mean if you jump into water (and the pig doesn't take damage as a result) you don't get the achievement?)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means