# Easiest way to get the "ride a pig off a cliff" achievement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

I'm having some difficulty getting this achievement - currently I am placing my saddle on a pig close to a cliff, but as soon as I jump on the pig always turns around and walks back towards safety..

Any tips on getting my porcine friend to play nice?

Comment: Title should read "How do I ride a pig off a cliff?" :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how one guy got it done:

Comment: Seems like overkill, according to [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20844/how-high-must-a-cliff-be-to-fly-a-pig-off-of-it).

Comment: I agree, this is a little overkill but basically how I ended up doing it - you don't need to dig such a large pit, just enough for the pig to take damage

Comment: Once the pig is near the ledge, you can hit it (while still riding it) to bump it off. No need to wait for the pig to jump.

Comment: I can't help but think pushing it off with water would be easier than that video

Answer (score 17):

Update ver 1.4.2 added a Carrot on a Stick, an item used to control where the pig will move and where it will move.  Using that will enable you to easily control your pig for the achievement.

It is a good idea to have the Feather Falling enchantment on some armor to protect yourself from the fall; also advisable is having a pool of water below to break your fall (no fall damage, qualifies for achievement)

Comment: Carrot on a Stick was added on Oct 25, 2012 (ver 1.4.2). Added to dev versions on Sep 6th, 2012 (12w36a).

Answer (score 11):

You can help yourself with a bucket of water placed opposite to the cliff. The flow will push the pig off.

Answer (score 3):

Use a carrot on a stick to guide the pig off the cliff, but it's recommended you have diamond boots enchanted with feather falling if the cliff is more than 22 blocks high.