# If I fly a pig off a cliff, but land in water, do I still get the achievement?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

The determining factor for getting the *Fly a Pig Off a Cliff* achievement seems to be that [the pig takes damage on landing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/20870/3610). Is this actually the case? I'm wondering whether landing the pig in water would work, event though it won't take damage.

Comment: If (achievement IFF damage) then no achievement if no damage.  You've already answered the question.  Do you mean to be asking whether damage is actually required?

Comment: As I said, `seems to be`, I don't know how the actual mechanism works.

Comment: Edited to ask about the mechanism.

Comment: try it, i suppose that's quicker then asking here

Comment: I've already got it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just tested this, and the answer is **no**, the poor piggy must get hurt. :(
[image: a little cheating]
[image: proof that nothing good ever comes from trying to appease PETA]

Comment: awww! poor piggy!

Comment: Won't that most likely kill the pig? Just like when Spider-jockeys fall and the spider dies, cushioning the skeleton's fall

Comment: @JefreyLin: If it lands in deep enough water, that cushions it so it doesn't get hurt at all. Normally it might. It only has to be three high to get the achievement though.